# Why Does a micro instance if RH7.2 return "Non-Windows instances with a virtualization type of 'hvm' are currently not supported ...."?

Tags: amazon-ec2, chef-infra, test-kitchen

My kitchen.yml looks like.

```
driver:
  name: ec2
  require_chef_omnibus: true
  instance_type: t2.micro
  block_device_mappings:
    - ebs_device_name: /dev/sda1
      ebs_volume_type: standard
      ebs_virtual_name: test
      ebs_volume_size: 50
      ebs_delete_on_termination: true
transport:
  ssh_key: /home/atg/.ssh/id_rsa
  connection_timeout: 10
  connection_retries: 5

provisioner:
  name: chef_zero

# Uncomment the following verifier to leverage Inspec instead of Busser (the
# default verifier)
# verifier:
#   name: inspec

platforms:
    - name: redhat-7.2
      driver:
        image_id: ami-2051294a
      transport:
        username: root
    - name: ubuntu-14.04
      driver:
        image_id: ami-fce3c696
      transport:
        username: ubuntu

suites:
  - name: default
    run_list:
      - recipe[ssh::default]
      - recipe[python::default]
      - recipe[git::default]
      - recipe[ureka::default]
     attributes: 
      ssh:
        options': {'Compression': 'yes', 'ForwardX11': 'yes', 'X11UseLocalhost': 'yes', 'UsePAM': 'no'}
```

kitchen converge returns

> Create failed on instance . Please see
>   .kitchen/logs/default-redhat-72.log for more details
>   ------Exception------- Class: Kitchen::ActionFailed Message: InvalidParameterCombination => Non-Windows instances with a
>   virtualization type of 'hvm' are currently not supported for this
>   instance type.

Comment: Is the instance being created within VPC?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use an AMI that is not compatible with the instance instance type, or at least something thinks you are. This is odd because t2.micro should support HVM AMIs. I would turn up the logging to see where the error is coming from (`kitchen create redhat -l debug`).